# How to use GROUP_CONCAT to grab data for row ID?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

The query will retrieve IDs and all Attachment IDs as inline values like this

```
ID | Attachments 
26| 299,300,301,10922,11286,45927,45939
63| 299,300,301,10922,11286,45927,45939
73| 299,300,301,10922,11286,45927,45939
91| 299,300,301,10922,11286,45927,45939
103| 299,300,301,10922,11286,45927,45939
```

As you can see, the list for attachments repeats itself since I hardcoded it to fetch `WHERE pl_posts.post_parent = 26`. How can I change this hardcoded value so that it finds all attachment for that row post ID? If I replace that line to `WHERE pl_posts.post_parent = pl_posts.ID` I get NULL for everything so I am not sure if this is right?

```
SELECT 
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS pl_posts.ID,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pl_posts.ID)
        FROM pl_posts
        WHERE pl_posts.post_parent = 26
        AND pl_posts.post_type = 'attachment' 
        ORDER BY pl_posts.post_date DESC
    ) AS Attachments
FROM pl_posts 
GROUP BY pl_posts.ID
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: Offtopic: Stop using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ` it has become deprecated since MySQL 8.0.17 and will be removed from MySQL..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: If you are using the output of group_concat for anything other than providing a list to be read by a human being, then you probably should not be using group_concat. A list of surrogate ids is meaningless - it looks like you are trying to solve the problem in the wrong way. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try aliasing the outer query's table to 'pl' so you can refer to it in the subquery's where clause:

```
SELECT pl.ID,
   (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pl_posts.ID)
        FROM pl_posts
        WHERE pl_posts.post_parent = pl.ID
        AND pl_posts.post_type = 'attachment' 
        ORDER BY pl_posts.post_date DESC
    ) AS Attachments
FROM pl_posts pl
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

This is not an aggregate query so don't you need the group by clause.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is rather meaningless

Answer (score 0):

You can write another select instead of the hardcoded value to select the field value with which you want to compare